# SQL DELETE очень медленный

Tags: sql, postgresql, delete

Удаление из таблицы занимает очень много времени.

```
delete from al_instances where alarmdefinition_id = 27076;
```

Всего 150 000 записей и удаляемых окло 55 000. Запрос выполняется 55 минут.
По моему опыту sql должен справляеться намного быстрее.

Я изменял конфигурации логгинга в postgresql.conf, но самые полные логи и видимо моя неопытность в них не дала мне полезной информации.

С чем может быть связана проблема? Как я могу найти больше информации чтобы это понять?

Comment: какие нибудь триггера, внешние ключи, которые надо проверять, большое количество индексов есть ?

Comment: Какая СУБД? `plsql` - это oracle, `postgresql.conf` - это postgresql.

Comment: Для postgresql по сути затрат времени ответит `explain (analyze,buffers) delete from ...` (только осторожно, это реально выполнит запрос)

Comment: @Мелкий Прошу прощения, postgres конечно

Comment: @Mike К сожаления я не настолько разбираюсь в БД. Не знаю что такое триггеры. Это связано с зависимостями с другими таблицами?  Индексы, это разве не соотносительно с количеством строк в таблице?

Comment: к вышесказанным версиям, возможно `SELECT` выполняется также долго... тогда вероятная причина в отсутствии индекса по `alarmdefinition_id`...